# ¿Como obtener la longitud de un array dentro de otro array?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
  $arrDatos = array("12.1", "32.40", "31.943", "65.45", "19.302", "75.31", "48.421", "12.345", "65.432");
```

Necesito sacar el promedio de sus valores, pero esto se hace dependiendo del número  de elementos en los que se quiera dividir el arreglo, es decir, si se necesita sacar el promedio a cada 4 elementos, se extraerán los 4 primeros valores, después los siguientes 4 y así sucesivamente. Para extraer estos datos utilizo la función array_chunk(), y obtengo el siguiente array:

```
    Array ( 
    [0] => Array 
      ( 
        [0] => 12.1 [1] => 32.40 [2] => 31.943 [3] => 65.45 
      ) 
    [1] => Array 
    ( 
      [0] => 19.302 [1] => 75.31 [2] => 48.421 [3] => 12.345 
    ) 
    [2] => Array 
    ( 
      [0] => 65.432 
    ) 
)
```

Nótese que el ultimo arreglo tiene un solo elemento, entonces, para sacar el promedio se tendrían que sumar los valores de cada arreglo y dividirlo entre su propia longitud, el problema es que si hago un count() sobre el arreglo que obtuve al dividir el arreglo principal me da como resultado 3, entonces como podría obtener la longitud de los arreglos internos, para que pueda calcular el promedio como debe ser, ya que si coloco un número definido, el último valor será afectado por esto y eso dará un resultado erróneo.

A continuación pongo el código completo.

```
    <?php

  //Array original
  $arrDatos = array("12.1", "32.40", "31.943", "65.45", "19.302", "75.31", "48.421", "12.345", "65.432");

  //Dividir el array en partes
  $newArrDatos = array_chunk($arrDatos, 4);

  //Recorrido del array para obtener la sumatoria
  $suma = 0; 
  $arrProm = array(); //Array auxiliar para guardar los resultados
  foreach($newArrDatos as $key => $value){
    $suma = array_sum($value);
    echo $suma." | "; //Obtiene: 141.893 | 155.378 | 65.432 |
    array_push($arrProm, $suma = array_sum($value)/4);
  }
  print_r($arrProm); //Obtiene: Array ( [0] => 35.47325 [1] => 38.8445 [2] => 16.358 ), el ultimo promedio es erroneo
?>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considera que `$value` es un `array`, por lo que si usas `count($value)`, podrás saber cuantos valores existen dentro del mismo.

#### Solución:

```
array_push($arrProm, $suma = array_sum($value) / count($value));
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0084b3e650f69aff8682d972177f0f3ec5f96f86)</kbd>

Comment: Funciono bien, obtengo: Array ( [0] => 35.47325 [1] => 38.8445 [2] => 65.432 ) como resultados, gracias @Marcos

Comment: Otra cosa, intente mostrar el valor de count($value), con un echo, pero siempre me salia el último valor es decir 1, porque solo se muestra el último y no los anteriores, La prueba la hice tanto dentro como fuera del foreach()

Comment: @Robert_Rmz, si hiciste un `echo count($value)` dentro del `foreach`, si deberías haber visto la longitud correcta de cada uno y no solo la del último. [Aqui te dejo una demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/90abd50115db5cc316ddcf1383a14cb34b0a4cf4)

Comment: Ya veo, no lo hice de la forma correcta, gracias nuevamente

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener la longitud del primer arreglo, dentro del arreglo, deberias hacer algo asi:

```
$longitud1 = count($value[0]);
```

Que te dara como resultado 4. Si quieres obtener la longitud del segundo arreglo, seria algo asi

```
$longitud2 = count($value[1]);
```

Que te dara, igual, 4. Y asi sucesivamente para cualquier arreglo o elemento que este dentro del arreglo.